# can't drag to move, zoom in or out google-maps-react

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I'm trying to display a couple of markers in a map. On button click, I add in a marker and recenter the map to show all the markers.

```
function MapContainer(props) {
    var bounds = new props.google.maps.LatLngBounds(); 
    const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([
        {
            lat: 55.378, 
            lng: 3.436
        }, 
        {
            lat: 37.0902, 
            lng: 95.712
        }
    ]);

    const adjustMap = (mapProps, map) => {
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
            bounds.extend(new props.google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng))
    }, [markers])

    return (
        <>
        <div className={props.className}>
            <Map 
                google={props.google}
                style={{ borderRadius: '10px'}}
                zoom={7}
                bounds={bounds}
                onBoundsChanged={adjustMap}
            >
                {
                    markers.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <Marker position={{lat: item.lat, lng: item.lng}}/>
                        )
                    })
                }       
            </Map>
        </div>
        <button onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); console.log("hehe"); const hoho = [...markers, {lat: 59.913, lng: 10.752}]; setMarkers(hoho)}}>Add marker</button>
        </>
    );  
}
```

Now the issue is, I can't drag to move the map, nor can I zoom in or out. If I remove the onBoundsChanged property, I can drag and zoom, but if I include it, dragging and zooming doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in an infinite loop since because react is not doing a deep diff on your props and your props are continuously changing because it is a new LatLngBounds object over and over and over. Try passing primitives as props instead of an object.

See https://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples/issues/946 for further discussion around this.

Comment: I see the issue, but I don't understand why it's happening. My useEffect only runs once, which in turn updates the bounds once. So why is onBoundsChanged running continuously when bounds is only updated once in the useEffect?